# Redirect URI on kibana with HAProxy

Tags: url, redirect, uri, kibana, haproxy

I want to use the same host to get to my 2 diffenrents Kibana :

https://test.com/**kibana1**/app/kibana

and

https://test.com/**kibana2**/app/kibana

Each of the kibana can be assessible with https://aaa/app/kibana

Here is my HAProxy script :

```
acl k1 path_beg -m sub -i /kibana1
acl k2 path_beg -m sub -i /kibana2

use_backend KIBANA1 if k1
use_backend KIBANA2 if k2
redirect location /kibana1/app/kibana if k1
redirect location /kibana2/app/kibana if k2
```

But when I redirect, it doesn't know the URL.
How can I do to ignore kibana1 in the URL ?

How can I do it with HA Proxy ?

Answer (score 0):

Id recommend looking into using the roundrobin setting on your backend. That will loadbalance between your two kibana instances. Also, you would have it a lot better if you also simply routed by DNS name, and utilized DNS load balancing on your KB instances. Im assuming you are loading from the same elastic instance/data set.

The reason for why it not loading is your ACL isnt loading the backend.